# sed replace gives input caret instead of result

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I want to exchange an unknown hash to a known one in a file. Lot's of escaping needed...

An example for the line to replace:

```
define( 'PB_PASSWORD', 'ab57a5449b0781c91c4701ab6258655d' );
```

The target might be:

```
define( 'PB_PASSWORD', '438bb1dc13ec5cbdf3b938e4fc6c3748' );
```

This should be done in a linux shell script. I got this far with sed:

```
sed -i 's/define\( \'PB_PASSWORD\', \'[^“]*\' \);/define\( \'PB_PASSWORD\', \'438bb1dc13ec5cbdf3b938e4fc6c3748\' \);/' todo.txt
```

But all this does is give me an input

```
>
```

I tried several ways to achieve this and I think it's the escaping that keeps me from reaching my goal.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have curly quotes inside the `[^...]`. Is that what you intended?

Comment: You can avoid much of the escaping if you wrap the argument in double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: @Barmar Just using double quotes won't help, escaping is also off here (ERE used while the BRE flavor is defined by default).

Comment: The immediate problem is that you _cannot_ escape single quotes in single quotes; the backslash is just a literal backslash, and the single quote ends the string. The `>` is the shell telling you that (it thinks) you forgot the closing single quote.

Comment: Just changing quotes does not solve the issue. There are several unevident immediate issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```bash
sed "s/\(define( 'PB_PASSWORD', '\)[^']*/\1438bb1dc13ec5cbdf3b938e4fc6c3748/"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/7kqHhM).

Here, the POSIX BRE pattern is used:

- `\(define( 'PB_PASSWORD', '\)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this value from the RHS): the literal `define( 'PB_PASSWORD', '` text
- `[^']*` - any zero or more chars other than `'`.

Note it is fine to use a digit right after `\1` as you can only define up to 9 group backreferences in a POSIX regex flavor.

In your environment, you can  use

```bash
sed -i "s/\(define( 'PB_PASSWORD', '\)[^']*/\1438bb1dc13ec5cbdf3b938e4fc6c3748/" todo.txt
```